# I need to loop through and assign to multidimensional list Python

Tags: python

I am making a program which will calculate random groups for any given number of people/groups. But when I have an number of people that doesnt easily go into lets say 6. Then I want to loop through adding a person to each list until I have no more to add.

```
import random

classSize = int(input('How many people are there in the class?'))
classGroup = int(input('How many groups would you like to create?'))


classGroupNumber = classSize // classGroup
classGroupRemainder = classSize % classGroup

print(classGroupNumber)
print(classGroupRemainder)

count = 0
if classGroupRemainder == 0:
    randomClass = random.sample(range(1,classSize+1),classSize)
    for t in range(1,classGroup+1):
        print('\n')
        for i in range(0,classGroupNumber):
            count += 1
            print('group',t,'- Student - ',randomClass[count-1])
else:
    iterator = 0
    randomClass = random.sample(range(1,classSize+1),classSize)
    newList = [[] for x in range(classGroup)]
    while iterator < classSize:
        for i in range(0,1):
            newList[i].append(randomClass[iterator])
            iterator += 1
    print(newList)
    print(iterator)
    print(randomClass)
```

Basically say I have 15 people. I want to put these people into groups or teams. But I want to do this randomly and I want there to be fair teams. So if I have 15 people and I want 4 teams. I would have 3 groups of 4 people and 1 group of 3. As opposed to 5,4,3,3 or something similar. I am making this aimed at teachers and sports leaders that would like to create teams randomly to make it fair. I wanted to take a random sample of the amount of people in the class or sports club then add 1 of them to each list within a multidimensional array so that it keeps on looping through and adding them to the arrays until there are no more. This way I would create even teams.

It should function in a similar way to this.... http://chir.ag/projects/team-maker/

Comment: Relative to the amount of code given, the question doesn't provide enough information. What have you tried?

Comment: So, what happens? What error do you get?

Comment: Make a loop, have y groups, then the program place 1 person in each group until it hits classSize amount of people, then it stops

Answer (score 1):

Your post is a bit incomplete, but here's what I think you're asking for:

```
import random

classSize = int(input('How many people are there in the class? '))
classGroup = int(input('How many groups would you like to create?' ))
groups = [[] for i in range(classGroup)]
students = list(range(classSize))

for g in range(classGroup):
    group = random.sample(students, classSize//classGroup)
    groups[g].extend(group)
    group = set(group)
    students = [s for s in students if s not in group]

for s in students:
    random.choice(groups).append(s)
```

`groups` now contains a list of lists, where each sublist is a group of students

Comment: groups = [[] for i in range(classGroup)]
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @KyleKirkby: and try again

Comment: @KyleKirkby: I don't understand what you mean. You should elaborate on this and edit that elaboration into your question

Answer (score 0):

This approach ensures you always have similar sized groups.

```
import random

class_size = input('How many people are there in the class?')
n_groups = input('How many groups would you like to create?')
people = range(class_size)

groups = [[] for i in range(n_groups)]
for i in range(class_size):
    for group in groups:
        if not people:
            break
        person = random.choice(people)
        people.remove(person)
        group.append(person)

print groups
```

Comment: Rather than `people.pop(people.index(person))` you should just do `people.remove(person)`, which does both the searching and the removing in one step. It's not terribly efficient (`O(N)`) of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get a lot of what you want with slicing of a shuffled list. This avoids doing lots of pops or removals from a list, which are relatively poor performing (though really, performance isn't likely to matter for any reasonable sized group). This whole code should take `O(N+M)` time where `N` is the number of students and `M` is the number of groups (most of the other answers are `O(M*N)` or worse):

```
import random

def make_groups(class_size, num_groups):
    students = list(range(class_size))
    random.shuffle(students)

    group_size = class_size // num_groups    # size of the smaller groups
    smaller_groups = num_groups - class_size % num_groups # num of smaller groups

    # start with smaller groups
    groups = [students[i:i+group_size] for i in
              range(0, smaller_groups*group_size, group_size)

    # add longer groups
    groups.extend(students[i:i+group_size+1] for i in
                  range(smaller_groups*group_size, class_size, group_size+1)

    return groups

if __name__ == "__main__":
    class_size = int(input('How many people are there in the class?'))
    num_groups = int(input('How many groups would you like to create?'))
    for group in make_groups(class_size, num_groups):
        print group
```

An example run:

```
How many people are there in the class?30
How many groups would you like to create?7
[14, 27, 18, 5]
[15, 24, 23, 13]
[22, 6, 16, 1]
[4, 29, 0, 7]
[28, 2, 12, 26]
[11, 9, 3, 17, 21]
[10, 25, 20, 19, 8]
```

That produces five groups of four and two groups of five.